# How to import csv file and display the data on html table then save on sql database in asp .net core

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm struggling with importing csv file in my project.
I want to upload a csv file and display the data before saving to sql database.
I'm using asp .net core razor pages.
Here is my C# method for Importing:

```
  public ActionResult OnPostImport()
        {
            IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            string folderName = "Upload";
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string sFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
                ISheet sheet;
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, file.FileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    if (sFileExtension == ".xls")//This will read the Excel 97-2000 formats    
                    {
                        HSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
                        sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);
                    }
                    else //This will read 2007 Excel format    
                    {
                        XSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
                        sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);
                    }
                    IRow headerRow = sheet.GetRow(0);
                    int cellCount = headerRow.LastCellNum;
                    // Start creating the html which would be displayed in tabular format on the screen  
                    sb.Append("<table class='table'><tr>");
                    for (int j = 0; j < cellCount; j++)
                    {
                        NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICell cell = headerRow.GetCell(j);
                        if (cell == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.ToString())) continue;
                        sb.Append("<th>" + cell.ToString() + "</th>");
                    }
                    sb.Append("</tr>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
                    for (int i = (sheet.FirstRowNum + 1); i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
                    {
                        IRow row = sheet.GetRow(i);
                        if (row == null) continue;
                        if (row.Cells.All(d => d.CellType == CellType.Blank)) continue;
                        for (int j = row.FirstCellNum; j < cellCount; j++)
                        {
                            if (row.GetCell(j) != null)
                                sb.Append("<td>" + row.GetCell(j).ToString() + "</td>");
                        }
                        sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
                    }
                    sb.Append("</table>");
                }
            }
            return this.Content(sb.ToString());
        }
```

Here is my frontend code:

```
    <h2>Import</h2>
<br />
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="file" id="fUpload" name="files" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="dvData"></div>
</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btnUpload').on('click', function () {
            var fileExtension = ['xls', 'xlsx'];
            var filename = $('#fUpload').val();
            if (filename.length === 0) {
                alert("Please select a file.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                var extension = filename.replace(/^.*\./, '');
                if ($.inArray(extension, fileExtension) === -1) {
                    alert("Please select only excel files.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            var fdata = new FormData();
            var fileUpload = $("#fUpload").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;
            fdata.append(files[0].name, files[0]);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/ImportCSVFile?handler=ImportFromExcel",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                data: fdata,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.length === 0)
                        alert('Some error occured while uploading');
                    else {
                        $('#dvData').html(response);
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $('#dvData').html(e.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

they ajax call doesnt reach the c# method. Please help I'm not sure what is it I'm missing out on this code above.And also pleaae advise how i can get to save the data to sql after importing the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can try to change `public ActionResult OnPostImport()` to `public ActionResult OnPostImportFromExcel()`.Becasue your ajax url is `/Home/ImportCSVFile?handler=ImportFromExcel`.
2.Or you can change ajax url to `/Home/ImportCSVFile?handler=Import`.

result:

[image]

And about saving data to db,you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391736/how-to-save-records-after-importing-excel-sheet-into-asp-net-core-razor-pages).